# Cable internet from UPC to Ethernet adapter

Tags: internet, ethernet, authentication, coaxial

How does UPC provide the internet connection ? The data it's just coming through the coaxial cable, like LAN or there is some kind of authentication with the router ?
I'm asking this because I'm wondering if I can get another internet connection in my attic with an coaxial to Ethernet adapter or router, since the cable starts from there.

Thank you.

Comment: I thought you were referring to a bar code.  Apparently, there is an ISP named UPC.  Even so, it isn't clear exactly what you're asking.  Is there something special about their service that leaves you wondering how they do things in a different way?  Are you asking how the Internet works?  Please edit the question to clarify what specific question you're asking.

Comment: You need to contact the ISP about splitting the cable connection and installing another modem. However, it’s highly unlikely you can do that. If anything, you will have to buy and pay for a second internet connection. The way you should do this is run an Ethernet cable and use network switches / routers to segregate and extend your existing network as necessary.